# How to plot histogram with data prepared in Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plot, histogram

I have a Pandas DataFrame in the form of:

```
hour   activity
1      23
2      334
3      345
...
23     24
24     12
```

I just want to plot a histogram with 1-24 as bins and corresponding activity as value (height). Is there any simple way doing this in Pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could use [`df.plot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) for this:

```
df.plot('hour', 'activity', kind='bar')
```

This uses 'hour' values as the x-axis and 'activity' as the y-axis, specifying that a bar chart should be drawn.

Example:

```
>>> hour = range(1, 25)
>>> activity = np.random.randint(1, 10, 24)
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'hour': hour, 'activity': activity})
>>> df.plot('hour', 'activity', kind='bar');
```

Which produces:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
df.plot('hour','activity',kind='bar',rot=0)
```

where df is your dataframe, rot is added to rotate the labels

Comment: that doesn't work, when hour is index? because when I used df.hist(), it takes my activity as bins and hour as y value